# Javascript script (ajax) not working (php+ajax for live search)

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax

I tried to make live search with php and ajax but this function is not working at not it's not entering the script.. I don't know why.
The **PHP code is working.**

```
<form autocomplete="off">
    <input type="search" id="search" name="search" placeholder="Search..." />
</form>

<br>

<div id="search_result"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search").keyup(function(){
        $("search_result").show();
        var txt = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type="GET",
            url:"fetch.php",
            data:"q=" + txt,
            success:function(data)
            {
                $("#search_result").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: `$search("#search")` this part looks a bit weird...

Comment: You should remove the extra `search` from `$search("#search").keyup(function(){` should be `$("#search").keyup(function(){`

Comment: Still not working, fixed but its not the the problem...

Comment: @Ramptor what exactly not working?

Comment: @Ramptor what content contains "data" variable?

Comment: @Ramptor did you saw any errors in console?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`type="GET"` should be `type: "GET"`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("search_result").show();
```

should be

```
$("#search_result").show();
```

and as mentioned

```
type="GET",
```

should be

```
type: "GET",
```

What is the php code returning?
And what are the console errors?